# Does confint() return the CI in log odds or odds?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confidence-interval

I'm using confint to get the CI of odds of a logistic model. The estimates I'm receiving are in logodds, and I have to convert them by using exp(). Do I have to do the same thing for the CI as well as its returned by confint()?

[image]

Comment: generally yes, but it would be helpful if you showed us example output to be sure. (One pretty easy way to tell that your CIs are on the log-odds scale are (1) if they bracket the point estimate as given on the log-odds scale and (2) if the lower CI limit is negative ...)

Comment: @BenBolker You're right; I added the picture for more context.